Static mocking is already registered - even with try-with-resources
I have an utility class ConverterUtil with a method convertJsonToFileBytes and two test classes(WorkflowExportServiceTest,WorkflowExportControllerTest). If I run the test classes individually everything works, but when I execute all the tests it gives me an error:
[ERROR] Errors: 
[ERROR]   WorkflowExportServiceTest.given_workflowId_shouldConvertToJSONFile:60 Mockito 
For com.closeupinternational.baseproject.util.ConverterUtil, static mocking is already 
registered in the current thread

To create a new mock, the existing static mock registration must be deregistered

WorkflowExportServiceTest:
@SpringBootTest(properties = "spring.cloud.config.enabled=false")
@Slf4j
class WorkflowExportServiceTest {
...

@Test
void given_workflowId_shouldConvertToJSONFile() throws IOException {
  try (MockedStatic<ConverterUtil> utilities = Mockito.mockStatic(ConverterUtil.class)) {
       utilities.when(() -> ConverterUtil.convertJsonToFileBytes(any(), any(), any())).thenReturn(new byte[0]);
       ...
  }
}

WorkflowExportControllerTest:
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(WorflowExportController.class)
class WorkflowExportControllerTest {
...

@Test
void given_workflowId_shouldReturnJsonExportedFromWorkflow() throws Exception {
  try(MockedStatic<ConverterUtil> utilities = Mockito.mockStatic(ConverterUtil.class)){
      utilities.when(() -> ConverterUtil.convertJsonToFileBytes(any(),any(),any())).thenReturn(new byte[0]);
      ...
  }
}

Why the mockStatic is not closing even with try-with-resoucers?
pom.xml:
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
...
<properties>
    <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
    <java.version>21</java.version>
        ...
</properties>
...
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
   <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
   <version>5.2.0</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

Updated: One test is to a controller test and another to a service test. MockedStatic is on mockito-core:5.11.0

What versions (JDK, JUnit & Mockito) do you use? What test isolation do you use? Or do you use any parallelism for running tests? It seems like both tests are running in the same thread at the same time. So fare I hadn't any such issue and I use in in test running in pipeline within 8 threads.

Have you tried mocking the same static resource in the same test with the autoclosabel try statement around it twice and see if that works or throsw the same Error? For me  this works as intendend and the static mock is closed. A repeated Static mock is therefore possible. If that also works for you, it has somehow todo with setup. I have tried with java 17, spring boot  3.2.6 and spring-boot-starter-test instead of an explicit mockito dependency

In the same test with autocloseable it worked. Have you ever tried with two different files and got it the same error? @GJohannes
